# Can a weaker version of the Hausdorff paradox be proved without AC?

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, axiom-of-choice

The [Hausdorff paradox](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hausdorff_Paradox) is an incredibly counter-intuitive consequence of the axiom of choice; it is also important for demonstrating the non-existence, under AC, of a rotation-invariant measure on the discrete $\sigma$-algebra of the sphere.

But there is a part of the Hausdorff paradox that seems consistent with the existence of a rotation-invariant measure on the discrete $\sigma$-algebra, and yet still seems (to me) very counter-intuitive; so I am curious as to whether it can be proved without AC:

> > Is it a theorem of "ZF + Dependent Choice" that there exists a non-empty set $A \subset \mathbb{S}^2$ and rotations $R,R' \colon \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ such that $R(A)$ is disjoint from $A$ and $R'(A)=A \cup R(A)\,$?
> >
> > Is it, at least, a theorem of "ZF + Dependent Choice" that there exists a non-empty set $A \subset \mathbb{S}^2$ and a rotation $R \colon \mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2$ such that $A \subsetneq R(A)\,$?

(I fear there's some really obvious construction of such a set $A$ that I've missed - but I'll take the risk and ask the question!)

Comment: With only ZF+DC, it is consistent that everything is measurable, so you cannot have identity of that sort that break "conservation of measure". But what you are asking is probably possible as one can take $A$ to have zero measure. for example, take a faithful action of the free group $F_2$ on the sphere, pick a point $p$ which is not a fixed point of any element of $F_2$, then the orbit of $p$ is isomorphic as a $F_2$ set to $F_2$ itself, and hence you are going to be able to find inside the orbit something very close to what you are asking using a paradoxical decomposition of $F_2$

Comment: Yes to the second question, by A = {(cos(n), sin(n), 0): n in N}, let S = clockwise rotation by 1 radian.

Comment: $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ is a weaker (but still incredibly counterintuitive) version of the Hausdorff paradox which can be proved without AC.

Comment: I disagree with @bof.

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestion in the first comment below my question (and with the help of the second comment), I can give an example of a scenario that is *"even worse"* than what I requested, where $A \cup R(A)$ is a proper subset of $R'(A)$.

(Finding an example where we actually have *equality* is proving remarkably difficult to me, so ***I still invite answers regarding having equality, i.e.*** $A \cup R(A)=R'(A)$.)

Regard $\mathbb{S}^2$ as the unit sphere about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Fix $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos(\alpha)$ is transcendental, and define the matrices
\begin{align*}
M_1 \ &= \ \left( \begin{array}{c c c}
\cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 \\
\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right) \\
& \\
M_2 \ &= \ \left( \begin{array}{c c c}
\cos(\alpha) & 0 & -\sin(\alpha) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha)
\end{array} \right).
\end{align*}

According to p227 of [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=obxDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=&source=bl&ots=zzJfg5Ofjw&sig=2X-OfARPQWFF1DF5wNEBidtXAU8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBoNP6t67SAhXDFywKHXh-BC4Q6AEIRDAH#v=onepage&q&f=false), since $\cos(\alpha)$ is transcendental, $\{M_1,M_2\}$ forms a generating set of a free group contained in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$; and by Euler's rotation theorem, each non-trivial member of the group $G$ generated by $\{M_1,M_2\}$ fixes exactly 2 points. Hence (since $\mathbb{S}^2$ is uncountable) there exists a point $x^\ast \in \mathbb{S}^2$ which is not fixed under any non-trivial member of $G$.

Let $G^+$ be the monoid generated by $\{M_1,M_2\}$, and take
\begin{align*}
A \ &= \ \{M_1Mx^\ast : M \in G^+\} \\
R \ &= \ M_2M_1^{-1} \\
R' \ &= \ M_1^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Then $R(A)=\{M_2Mx^\ast : M \in G^+\}$ and $R'(A)=\{Mx^\ast : M \in G^+\}$. So $A$ is disjoint from $R(A)$, and
$$ R'(A) \ = \ A \cup R(A) \cup \{x^\ast\}. $$